# Sharepoint online - configure internal user whit @mydomain account as guest

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, groups, external-users

We are hiring a new contributor who must have a corporate account.

Beacuse is like an outsider, we don't want him accessing the company intranet.

With corporate account any user is added to the "all users (membership)" group as MEMBER

There is a way to configure a user as GUEST in the "all users (membership)" ?

Another way could be give an explicit deny to a group for a site / folder?

Thanks Marco

Answer (score 0):

You could build a Conditional Access policy in Azure AD to block the access to SharePoint Online for the user. Read here for more:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/concept-conditional-access-policies